# How to make laptop's battery last long?

Tags: battery, battery-life

My uncle warns me to use laptop after charge.But sometimes I use it during charging,like...when I am watching videos or working my homework.I want to know that is that good to use laptop during charge for long??Because I sometimes can't give time to charge battery.So I have to use it in that way.And I don't want my battery to damage.Thank you.

Comment: If it's plugged in for a long time, take the battery out (if possible). If not, use tools to limit the amount it can charge from and too (eg, don't charge it more than 85% of the battery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping the charger connected with a full battery shouldn't do any harm with a modern laptop, it is smart enough to bypass the battery and directly supply the laptop from the charger.

Some general tips to keep the battery capacity high for some time is to usually not drain it of all capacity but try charging it up while it still has some charge left. Keeping the battery charge cycles flat tends to extend battery life.

Even though with a new battery it is recommended to charge it fully, then discharge it until it is (almost) empty and then charge it full again. After that keep to the above cycle style. This way the device can "learn" how to properly use the battery.

Comment: So you mean that I should use it to 15% or 10% and I have to recharge it to 100% again without using when plug in?? Right? Thank you so much

Comment: Yes, thats what you do the first time when you get a new laptop or basicly any device using a LiPO or LiIon battery eg. smartphones or tablets.

You can also keep using the device during that time, just make sure it is one continous charge from low charge until it is full again.

Answer (score 0):

Close Programs and Services You don't use(Be careful!If you Close system Programs or services You can damage your Computer!)

You can use your Computer when it is charging but Don't Charge Long.If you are charging when battery is %100 This will damage your battery.If you damage it You must to use computer plugged every time if you unplug it your computer will shutdown.(Sorry for Bad English)

Answer (score 0):

### Every laptop has it own battery capacity like mobile phones but you can make it run long by these ways :

1. First of all reduce the brightness to lowest.
2. Close application when you are not using.
3. You may install some 3rd party apps to reduce battery consumption to lowest.

when battery meter is about 98% unplug and replug the charger it will show not charging(in battery meter) that means it is running in direct electric power. It is always better to play games in plug in,
otherwise it may reduce battery life.For normal work charge and fully use batter to 10% after that charge again.